# Elasticsearch clone index return 400

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to clone my index, i have done what shown in this  [page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-clone-index.html) to clone the index using this command.

```
POST /my_index/_clone/my_index_clone
```

I also tried to make the index read-only first with this command

```
PUT /my_index/_settings
{   "settings": {
  "index.blocks.write": false
  }
}
```

But i always get this error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parse_exception",
        "reason": "request body is required"
      }
    ],
    "type": "parse_exception",
    "reason": "request body is required"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Can someone help me on this? Thank you

Comment: try just adding empty {} on the line after POST

Comment: it's not working, so i just create a script to match all document inside my index, and insert it to new index by myself. Thanks